# How can test a resource collection structure?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Sometimes we need to write a unit test for `collections`, There are some methods for testing JSON structure in feature test, but in the unit test there is no way to test structures! of course, some `assertions` exist for checking keys but that is not what I want. I need a method like the [assertJsonStructure](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#assert-json-structure) to do.

#### Example

Assume that we have a resource collection like this:

##### ExampleResource

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ExampleResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first_field' => $this->first_field,
            'second_field' => SecondExampleResource::collection($this->second_field),
        ];
    }
}
```

##### SecondExampleResource

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class SecondExampleResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'foo' => $this->foo,
            'bar' => $this->bar,
        ];
    }
}
```

Now I want to test when I make a collection from `ExampleResource` that the keys will be something like this:

```php
$example = ExampleResource::collection(Example::all());

$this->assertJsonStructure($example, [
    '*' => [
        'first_field',
        'second_field' => [
            '*' => [
                'foo', 'bar'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Comment: Can you provide examples of the data to test against and clarify what it is you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @Peppermintology I update the question, I think it should be pretty clear

Comment: Does the [`assertJsonFragment`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#assert-json-fragment) method help you at all?

Comment: @Nothehi nothing is preventing you to write a Unit test, but when you test _API Resources_ usually you only do feature tests because you are testing what it is being returned from a Controller (hence you are calling `$this->post` or `$this->get`, etc, that is a Feature test), so you should be having and passing the needed data for your controller to pass hat model or models to the resource and then the resource is going to return what you have coded inside it.